# Custom styling a header in sphinx website

Tags: html, css, markdown, python-sphinx

I want to centre-align and additionally bold the header in a sphinx website, defined in a markdown file as:

```
# MyHeader
```

I have tried putting

```
.center h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

in `_static/css/custom.css` but it does not work (other css in this file is working).

Ideally I would like to use HTML directly e.g.

`<h1 style="text-align: center;"><b>MyHeader</b></h1>`

This works great to render, but all of the titles are set to `<no title>` and the page does not appear on the TOC tree. Is there a way to make sphinx recognise this raw html as a header?

Comment: remove the `.center` from your CSS. Just `h1` should suffice.

Comment: Thanks @mb21 this works nicely! Do you know if it's possible to get `sphinx` to recognise the html-formatted header as the header or another way to tailor this to specific headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just center all h1s:

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

AFAIK, Sphinx used MyST for markdown under the hood. [Their docs](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/syntax/typography.html) say that if the [`attrs_block` extension is enabled](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/syntax/optional.html#syntax-attributes-block), you can use this markdown:

```
{.center}
# MyHeader
```

Which should work with this CSS:

```css
h1.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mb21! This is almost working, I had to use `.center {...}` instead of `h1.center {...}` but it was working nicely. One problem I realised using other css (e.g. `text-indent: 8 px`) is that all other text on the page is also formatted. I couldnt figure out how to get `attrs_inline` to work with header.  If you have any ideas that's great, otherwise I'll accept because it's answered the main question. Thanks!

Comment: "all other text on the page is also formatted" – then you need to use a CSS selector that doesn't target all these elements. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_selectors/Selectors_and_combinators